# Is a good idea to edit ETS2/ATS questions to make them suitable for both games?

Tags: discussion, tags

About Euro Truck Simulator 2 and American Truck Simulator: They are both truck simulators made by SCS Software with the same game engine and set of features with a couple of exceptions. As of 1.34 they are:

- Maps (ATS is US States, ETS2 is European Countries)
- Trucks (ATS is Peterbilt and Kenworth, ETS2 is Scania, Volvo and more)
- Detours (ATS has them, ETS2 does not)
- Specific Configuration Values (USD is on ATS and EUR is not, for example)

Because they are *technically* the same under the hood, I feel that the following types of questions should be edited to cover both games:

- [Does the amount of petrol affect your car's performance?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/351469/199843) (the mentioned setting works the same in both games)
- [How can I decrease Autosave frequency?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/351432/199843) (both have the auto saving feature)
- [Do horns affect AI?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/351414/199843) (self explanatory)
- [How can I boost mouse cursor speed in game menu?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/351372/199843) (same here)

As an "ideal scenario", you can take [What's the point of doing (ETS/ATS) World of Trucks External Contracts?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/309973/199843) as this question is tagged and applies to both games.

Should this be done when is possible?

Answer (score 3):

No.

It is impossible to know, before asking, if the answer to a question is the same for both games, especially if you've only played one (or neither). Since the answers could differ and be in theory entirely unrelated, a question asking for both should be closed as "Too broad".

When asking about mechanics in two separate games, knowledge of one answer does not imply knowledge of the other answer, which either invites incomplete answers which only address one game, or alienates users who would be able to answer a question about just one of the games.