# Should sports games tags be mixed in one series?

Tags: discussion, tags

If you search for the tags of F1, NHL, NBA, Madden, et cetera, we see a bunch of tags that don't have many questions, and that are repetitive ([nhl-14](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nhl-14), [nhl-15](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nhl-15), [nhl-17](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nhl-17))

Also, it's not like these games completely reinvent themselves every year. A question for [nhl-14](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nhl-14) might still apply in [nhl-17](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nhl-17).

Should sport games questions be mixed into one big category like [nhl-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nhl-series) to prevent all those repetitive tags?

Answer (score 9):

Much like for [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13366/is-a-good-idea-to-edit-ets2-ats-questions-to-make-them-suitable-for-both-games), no. Each game should be tagged individually. Tags are not expensive, and on Arqade they are not deleted when they're only applied to one question, so nothing is preventing us from tagging our questions properly.

Comment: Agreed. You also don't want to draw the line on all sport games year-to-year. NHL05 is way different than NHL15 for example. I think it's important to have separators for yearly sport games.

Comment: Think it's mostly that seeing a tag with only 1 or 2 questions irks me. Which I think it's why the example of Truck Driving is ok, but the sport series is not in my book.

Comment: @Fredy31 You can always ask more questions about those games ;)

Answer (score 1):

In conjunction to what Wrigglenite has already mentioned, I want to highlight one other reason we should not be combining the games into a single tag. In your question you state that a question for [nhl-14](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nhl-14) *might* apply to a question for [nhl-17](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nhl-17) however, there is also a good chance it might not. The core mechanics may stay very similar, but there a number of things that change with each new game.

In the case where we only had one tag for the entire series, it would be much harder to search for answers specific to the specific game you are playing, whereas currently you can simply filter by tag. Tags are cheap, and help filter questions more easily, so we should use them for each game. There is no  issue having a few duplicate questions across different games in a series.